# Using ptrace to read a block of memory from another proccess in c

Tags: c

I've been working on this code for a few hours and am out of ideas. Might be the way I'm using the `read()` function or but the output of the program is always the same.

> OUTPUT: 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}

trailed by some garbage characters

Probably some silly mistake in my coding, haven't coded in c for almost 2 years before today...

Anyway if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

```
int attach(int start, int pid)
{
    long ret;

    if ( start == 1 )
    {
        ret = ptrace (PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    }else{
        ret = ptrace (PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if ( ret < 0 )
    {
        printf("Could not attach to pid\n"); exit(-1);
    }

    waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);

    return(ret);
}

int dump(int pid, unsigned long long addr, unsigned long long endaddr, char *outfile)
{
    int output;
    int mem_fd;
    char mem_file_name[2048];
    unsigned long long size = endaddr - addr;
void *buf=malloc(size);
memset(buf,0,size);

    // attach
    attach(1,pid);

    // open the memory
    sprintf(mem_file_name, "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
    mem_fd = open(mem_file_name,O_RDONLY);
    lseek(mem_fd,addr,SEEK_SET);
    read(mem_fd,buf,size);

    // Cleanup
    attach(0,pid);
    close(mem_fd);
    free(buf);
}
```

EDIT: also I'm passing the addresses from /proc/$pid/maps through a shell script... They seem to be calculating the right start and end addresses.

`ptrace` is attaching to the process and stopping it..

EDIT2: also check it is reading the correct number of bytes into the buffer, it is... And reports it is seeking to the correct address.... which does seem like a rather high number for a memory address....

EDIT3: That got me thinking that the hex addresses in /proc/$pid/maps are in reversed order or swapped at the 4 byte mark... system endianess...

EDIT4: Just realized the address are only 6 bytes long... still haven't gotten it working though

EDIT5: I have a python program from these forums which works, and I've repeated the steps in c, but my program fails.... checked the python program and it is reading the address exactly the same as my program.... Have my program run parallel calls to the python calls and still it fails to read the correct memory... Link to python example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/how-to-re-load-all-running-applications-from-swap-space-into-ram)

Comment: aren't you supposed to use mapping? /proc/pid/maps? Anyway, what I would do first is to check/print errno and return codes after each operations.

Comment: I'm taking an address from /proc/XXXX/maps... like
 7ff223704000-7ff223705000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 58993341                   /usr/bin/leafpad and converting that to a range then reading /proc/xxxx/mem... 

reversing the address from there didn't work, froze my computer for a minute, switching endianness on the ranges didn't work either

Comment: Have a fuller version of the code with error checking, not getting any errors..... just not reading the correct location in the memory

Comment: Are you compiling as 64bit ? lseek() -> lseek64() might help as well

Comment: Yeah thanks that helped, had tried lseek64 before, but didn't add #define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE at the start like the man page said to

Comment: `Just realized the address are only 6 bytes long`. This is due to prcessor having `address sizes : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual`, I believe. `cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to  Severin Pappadeux for pointing out where i was going wrong, bellow is the final working code.

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int dump(int pid, long long, long long, char *outfile);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc < 5 )
        return(-1);

    int pid=strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
    long long addr=strtoll(argv[2],NULL,16);
    long long endaddr=strtoll(argv[3],NULL,16);

#if DEBUG   
    printf("Accessing pid memory %d from %llu to %llu\n",pid,addr,endaddr);
#endif

    dump(pid,addr,endaddr,argv[4]);

    return(0);
}

int attach(int start, int pid)
{
    long ret;

    if ( start == 1 )
    {
        ret = ptrace (PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    }else{
        ret = ptrace (PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    }

#if DEBUG
    if ( ret < 0 )
    {
        printf("Could not attach to pid\n"); exit(-1);
    }
#endif

    waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);


    return(ret);
}

int dump(int pid, long long addr, long long endaddr, char *outfile)
{
    int output;
    int mem_fd;
    char mem_file_name[2048];
    long long size = endaddr - addr;
    void *buf=malloc(size);
    memset(buf,0,size);
    long long readErr,writeErr,seekErr;

    // attach
    attach(1,pid);

    // open the memory
    sprintf(mem_file_name, "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
    mem_fd = open64(mem_file_name,O_RDONLY);
    output = open64(outfile,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
    seekErr=lseek64(mem_fd,addr,SEEK_SET);
    readErr=read(mem_fd,buf,size);
    writeErr=write(output,buf,size);

#if DEBUG
    printf("Allocated %lu usable bytes\n",malloc_usable_size(buf));
    printf("File %s block size is %llu bytes\n",mem_file_name,size);
    printf("Memory file value %d\n",mem_fd);
    printf("Seeked %llu Bytes\n",seekErr);
    printf("Read %llu Bytes\n",readErr);
    printf("Wrote %llu Bytes\n",writeErr);
    printf("\n\n");
#endif

    // Cleanup
    attach(0,pid);
    close(mem_fd);
    close(output);
    free(buf);
}
```